# debugging process that compiled in remote machine

Tags: c++, c, macos, debugging, lldb

I compiled Xcode project in debug mode. however, while running it from VM with lldb (or any other remote machine), I cannot see any debug symbols.

to resolve this I've created a soft link to the project source code in local compilation machine, so that each file will have the same path.

however, unlike local VM, in remote machine i might not have source code access.

so my question is what files should i copy from project debug outputs in compilation machine, to remote machine so that the lldb debugger will recognize target symbols, and how should i "tell" lldb to look at those new data, rather than the original symbols location (in compilation machine)

Comment: Source code debugging is different from availability of symbols. Try: http://lldb.llvm.org/remote.html

Comment: @jxh : I don't need remote debugging as I'm capable of logging to the remote machine and attach the lldb to a running process. the only problem is lack of debugging info

Comment: Remote debugging might be an easier solution than copying your source code around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the normal build/debug cycle lldb reads debug information from the .o files made in the course of the build.  There's a "debug map" in the binary produce that points to the locations of these .o files.  Since the debug map records absolute paths, if you want to use the .o files on another machine the .o files must appear in the same place on the file system as they are on the builder.

The other way to do this is to use Xcode's "DWARF + dSYM" variant of debug info generation, which builds a ".dSYM" folder that contains fully linked debug information.  Then just move the dSYM & the binary to the same directory and lldb will find it.  If for some reason that doesn't work, there is also an lldb command: `add-dsym` that you can use to manually tell lldb where the dSYM is.

Comment: To be clear, the above description only applies to building programs on OS X.